# Where clause applied to IQueryable does not filter

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework 7 RC1 I have the following query:

```
var result1 = context.Messages
  .Where(x => x.FromId == 4)
  .ToList();
```

Which returns 1 message. But if I create the query by steps:

```
IQueryable<Message> messages = context.Messages.AsQueryable();

messages.Where(x => x.FromId == 4);

var result2 = messages.ToList();
```

I get all messages when I should only get one. Why?

I need to build the query with conditions that is why I am doing this.

Comment: `messages = messages.Where(x => x.FromId == 4);`

Comment: Of course! Thanks.